# Is it better to create control object or methods to handle the relation between two objects?

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

Let's say i have a game, in the game the player is allowed to buy or sell items form/to the seller in the design level what is the best chooes to do, create another class to do the transactions, or should each class to have it's own buy/sell methods to handel the operations, or both of these are wrong :) ?

The second scenario will look like this:

```
public class Player {
    privte int money;
    // Other fields
    List<Integer> itemsPrice = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> itemsCart = new ArrayList<>();
    public void buy(){
        // Add item to itemsCart 
        // decrease the amount of money
    }
    public void sell(){
        // remove item from itemsCart 
        // increase the amount of money
    }
}

class Seller{
    private int money;
    List<Integer> itemsPrice = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> itemsCart = new ArrayList<>();
      public void buy(){
        // Add item to itemsCart 
        // decrease the amount of money
    }
    public void sell(){
        // remove item from itemsCart 
        // increase the amount of money
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an abstract class for both and extends that parent class and put the same

logic and variables into this parent class, for example, you have `money`, `itemsPrice`,

`itemCarts` in both `Player` and `Seller` you can add them into the parent class

```
public class Parent {

    protected int money;
    protected List<Integer> itemsPrice = new ArrayList<>();
    protected List<Integer> itemsCart = new ArrayList<>();
    public void buy(){
        // Add item to itemsCart 
        // decrease the amount of money
    }
    public void sell(){
        // remove item from itemsCart 
        // increase the amount of money
    }
}
```

, And `extends` Parent into `Player` and `Seller`

```
public class Player extends Parent {

}

public class Seller extends Parent {

}
```

, And usage of any of `Player` and `Seller`

```
Player p = new Player();
p.buy();
p.sell();

Seller s = new Seller();
s.buy();
s.sell();
```